# Set the default directory above the root directory for FileZilla Server

Tags: filezilla, ftp

What I would like to do is set the default directory above the root directory per user on FileZilla Server. I know this is possible with other FTP servers, but I can not seem to find where to set this for FileZilla Server.

For example, connecting with a FTP client, with no special instructions, the directory it reports when you do a `PWD` should be `/ScottC` instead of `/`.

I am having a little trouble figuring this out, when I try to search, all of the results are talking about setting up the default directory in FileZilla Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the FileZilla forms](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=13806) it can not be done.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to set the default paths in `Site Manager`

I have marked the steps below in the screenshot. Make sure you are in the `Advanced` tab in the Site Manager

[image: Steps to set default paths in Site Manager]